# Ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "for"

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg

```js
var dropdownsInsurance = ["home", "claims", "contact"];
     

 $.when(     
   for (var i = 0; i < dropdownsInsurance.length; i++) {
     $.get(dropdownsInsurance[i] + ".svg", function(svg) {
     $("#" + dropdownsInsurance[i]).append(svg.documentElement);
    });
   }
 
 ).then(init);
 
 function init() {
  alert("svgs have been loaded!");
 }
```

```css
.navLinkContainer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 25%;
}

svg {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="mainMenu" class="menu">
  <div class="navLinkContainer"><a id="home"></a></div>
  <div class="navLinkContainer"><a id="claims"></a></div>
  <div class="navLinkContainer"><a id="contact"></a></div>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure how to do a for loop inside a $.when jquery ajax call. It is not expecting the "for" . Here is a plunker link that allows the external svgs to be pulled inside. https://plnkr.co/edit/HEcvX7N7Ih29tCNPatw1?p=preview Anyway, same problem. How do I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  That's not how `$.when` works!  `$.when` takes *promise* objects as parameters, and returns a "combined" promise.

Comment: @gothical: Because he's calling `$.get` (which is *asynchronous*) inside the loop.

Comment: The answers provided by @RocketHazmat and myself give you working examples.

But, as a focus on your code, your error is trying to pass in a for loop directly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yup .. Was being too hasty .. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want your `init` function to run after all the `$.get` calls are done.  To do this you need to pass each promise returned from `$.get` to `$.when` as a parameter.  Also, you can't just stick a `for` loop inside a function call like that and expect it to work.

You need to build an array of promises, then use `.apply()` to send them to `$.when`.

```
var dropdownsInsurance = ["home", "claims", "contact"];

// Array to hold promises from `$.get` calls
var svg_promises = [];

function init(){
    alert("svgs have been loaded!");
}

// Closure to capture each value of `i`.
// Otherwise, `i` will be the same value
// at the end of the loop, because the callbacks
// will run after the `for` is done and will use
// that value of `i`.
function svg_callback(i){
    return function(svg){
        $("#" + dropdownsInsurance[i]).append(svg.documentElement);
    };
}

for(var i = 0; i < dropdownsInsurance.length; i++){
    // Add each promise to the array
    svg_promises.push($.get(dropdownsInsurance[i] + ".svg", svg_callback(i)));
}

// Call `$.when` with all the promises
$.when.apply($, svg_promises).then(init);
```

DOCS:

`Function.prototype.apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

`$.when`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Thanks Rocket. I am new to ajax and I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

**$.when()** is a pseudo promise offered by jQuery, it accepts Deferreds or Objects - such as functions, or Objects containing data.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

What's really handy, is that it can accept and array of functions to run, and it'll do it all synchronously for you.

```
    // Your original array
    var dropdownsInsurance = ["home", "claims", "contact"];

    // Made an array to collect functions into
    var applyList = [];

    // Use your for-loop outside of your pomise chain, and build an array of functions
for (var i = 0; i < dropdownsInsurance.length; i++) {
    // Add an array item
  applyList.push(
    function () {
        // In order to combat race condition in your array keys, affect your array directly
      // Do this by shifting off each one until you have them all moved into your function list
      // You may need to clone your original as you're changing it by using this
        var workOn = dropdownsInsurance.shift();
      // Go do your ajax and respond accordingly
      $.get(workOn + ".svg", function(svg) {
                    $("#" + workOn).append(svg.documentElement);
                });
  })
}

    // Create a "promise" chain
$.when()
// Ask your chain to apply all in your array
.always(applyList)
// Run your init function
.then(init)

    // Make your alert - tada
function init() {
  alert("svgs have been loaded!");
}
```

Here's the JS only in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ -- you might want to apply your own HTML and do some more work to it to get it working before you push into your own code.

Comment: Thanks Darren. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why are you using `always()` here?  This doesn't seem like the right place for that.  I don't think there's any guarantee here that `init` will be ran *after* all the `$.get` calls.

Comment: I made a test, and when using `.always()`, the `init` is called *before* the `$.get` callbacks.  See: https://jsfiddle.net/h471nw8s/1/

Comment: Using `$.when`, it'll wait until all `$.get` calls are done before calling `init`: https://jsfiddle.net/h471nw8s/2/