# Ajax Loop: Getting inconsistent results

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried my hand at an ajax loop and am getting inconsistent results (function results executed inside my init function after SVGs are retrieved and appended to id).

My inconsistent results are not there when I use multiple gets. It looks as though SVGs are retrieved and appended to the ids but have not executed inside the init properly, which leads me to believe that some functions inside the init may be encountered before the svg is retrieved and loaded. I am using document ready.

I usually use multiple gets inside a `when` followed by a `then` to fetch my images and append them to their id, but I want to get a more working knowledge of ajax. Because the SVGs are fetched externally, I did not include them here. However, all html and javascript (tried and true way of fetching svgs with multiple gets, and the inconsistent way using ajax loops) is included. Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong with the loop version?

```js
//tried and true way of loading svgs; consistent results
/*($(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
          
 $.when(
  $.get("pathToImgs/one.svg", function(svg) {
   $("#one").append(svg.documentElement);
  }),
  $.get("pathToImgs/two.svg", function(svg) {
   $("#two").append(svg.documentElement);
  }),
  $.get("pathToImgs/three.svg", function(svg) {
   $("#three").append(svg.documentElement);
  }),
  $.get("pathToImgs/four.svg", function(svg) {
   $("#four").append(svg.documentElement);
  }),
  $.get("pathToImgs/five.svg", function(svg) {
   $("#five").append(svg.documentElement);
  })
  })
 ).then(init);
          
 });
});*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {

    //new way of loading svgs; getting inconsistent results
    var path = "pathToImgs/";

    var categories = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

    var promises = [];

    function appendSvgToId(i) {
      return function() {
        promises.push($.get(path + categories[i] + ".svg", function(svg) {
          $("#" + categories[i]).append(svg.documentElement);
        }))
      }
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      svgMainPromises.push(appendSvgToId(i));
    };


    $.when()
      .always(promises)
      .then(init);

    function init() {
      alert("svgs loaded!");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div><a id="one"></a></div>
      <div><a id="two"></a></div>
      <div><a id="three"></a></div>
      <div><a id="four"></a></div>
      <div><a id="five"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.always()` with an array of promises and why do you have `promises` and `svgMainPromises`?

Comment: Hi Rocket, thank you for your reply. The svgMainPromises should be just "promises". I am sorry about that. As far as why I am calling .always with an array of promises, I thought this was okay to do. Can you show me a better way?

Comment: See my answer on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35134928/206403

Comment: Disregarding the svgMainPromises ( a remnant of my refactor to post this question on stackoverflow) , do you have a solution that explains my inconsistent results using the ajax loop?

Comment: So, what's the issue here?  Is your `init` being called at the wrong time?  Can you try to explain what "inconsistent results" means?

Comment: I am using Greensock and calling it inside the init function to initialize, create hover effects, and active states for each of my svgs that function as images for my navigation. When hovering hover some, the animation does not occur. This does not happen when loading my svgs and appending them to ids with multiple gets. I am fairly sure I can seperate the problem outside the init function and focus only on how I am loading the svgs via ajax.

Comment: Another thing I am struggling with Rocket and why I used the .always is because I would like to do other things after pushing objects onto the promise arrays

Comment: How do I take your "$.when.apply($, svg_promises).then(init);" and chain it to seperate $.get("pathToSvg/img.svg", function(svg) {
     $("#id").append(svg.documentElement);
    })

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are asking now.  Do you want to manually write multiple `$.get` statements or use a `for` loop?  If you want to chain another callback, you can use another `.then()`.

Comment: the reason I am using a manual $.get is because some images are located in standalone directories and do not warrant a loop

Comment: Okay, I will try the then

Comment: So, then just push them into `svg_promises` after the loop.

Comment: I added a new answer here with some new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait until all your SVGs are loaded before running `init`, then you need to pass the `$.get` calls to `$.when`.  Using `.always()` is *incorrect* here.

You just need to push promises into an array, doesn't matter whether it's manually or in a loop.

```
var path = "pathToImgs/";
var categories = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

// Array to hold promises from `$.get` calls
var svg_promises = [];

function init(){
    alert("svgs have been loaded!");
}

// Closure to capture each value of `i`.
// Otherwise, `i` will be the same value
// at the end of the loop, because the callbacks
// will run after the `for` is done and will use
// that value of `i`.
function svg_callback(i){
    return function(svg){
        $("#" + categories[i]).append(svg.documentElement);
    };
}

for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
    // Add each promise to the array
    svg_promises.push($.get(path+categories[i] + ".svg", svg_callback(i)));
}

// Add another SVG to the list
svg_promises.push($.get("extra.svg", function(svg){
    $("#extra").append(svg.documentElement);
}));

// Call `$.when` with all the promises
$.when.apply($, svg_promises).then(init).then(function(){
    // Second callback...
});
```

Comment: Hmm...I am not getting these to even load using your when. https://plnkr.co/edit/aQ6G9kSxTcEzUtBaHPTx?p=preview ; I use plunker when my question involves external resources like these svgs loading

Comment: I've modified your plunker to fit what @RocketHazmat is doing. [Take a look](https://plnkr.co/edit/3JPTfoigOSqjna0Lv0uQ)

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.Meeseeks.  LOOK AT ME!  Though, you still need to do `$.when.apply($, promises)`

Comment: @JohnStafford: You have too many `promises.push()` calls!  You want `promises` to be an array of *promises* (which are returned by `$.get`).  I created the `svg_callback` function because otherwise your callbacks would all use the same `i` value (it's an infamous AJAX loop issue).  You seem to be getting confused on how to use that.  If you want the `$.get` call to be in its own function, then you need to have that function `return $.get(...)`.  Check this out: https://plnkr.co/edit/QHSq61InDJ1oQOnzA7Sg?p=preview

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks: Because `$.when` takes promise/deferred objects as its parameters.  If you pass it an array, then the promise will resolve *immediately*.  It will *run*, but not work as intended.  `init` would run *before* the `$.get`s were done.  You use `.apply` so that each promise is passed as its own parameter to `$.when`.  (Did that make sense?)  I'm  Mr. Meeseeks, look at me!

Comment: Thanks Mr. Meeseeks, but the svgs aren't loading still. Your jquery inclusion does help though. :) Had that in my local and it doesn't load the svg with jquery either.

Comment: @JohnStafford: Check this out: https://plnkr.co/edit/QHSq61InDJ1oQOnzA7Sg?p=preview

Comment: so you are wrapping everything in an anonymous function?

Comment: @JohnStafford You'll notice that if you take out the anonymous function in RocketHazmat's plunker, it will still work.

Comment: @JohnStafford: I'm making a *closure* around `i`, otherwise all the callbacks would reference the same value (since it would be changing before they are ran).

Comment: uggh...just a second. I have to analyze your changes better to see why it is working now.

Comment: @JohnStafford: It's not *too* complicated.  What's going on is that you are looping over the array and calling a function for each element.  That function calls `$.get` and returns a promise.  All those promises are being combined using `$.when`.

Comment: yeah, your code is straight forward. I am really new to this and I have been sheltering you from my real problem until I cracked my fundamental one that you have showed me was a closure problem. how do I load multiple promise arrays into when? $.when.apply($, promiseArray1, promiseArray2, ...).then(init);

Comment: okay, I did away with the multiple promise array structures and just went with one and added everything to that and it seems to work. I would still be interested to know how you would add multiple different promises to the when statement though

Comment: No more inconsistent animations when my svgs load. Your ajax helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnStafford: `$.when.apply($, promiseArray1.concat(promiseArray2))`.  You need to pass *one* array to the [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.